# How to check telegram message type with Telegram bot api C#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I need to check message from telegram to my bot if this message is a photo I run specific command and if this message is a video file I run other command.
Now I do it something like this :

```
if(message.Photo != null){ //do something!}
```

Do you have any ideas how do it better than my variant? Maybe telegram api have message types?

Comment: What is type of the message variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have no other way to get type of update.

You can open issue to your library, or make a suggestion to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport).